# iteration of a variable over 2 lists in python using for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

What happens in the case of a following for loop in python? How will the values of i change in each iteration. Does the sequences x and y combine to form a single sequence?

```
for i in x, y:
    do_something(i)
```

The code on which I'm trying is like this:

```
for sentence in snippet, phrase:
    result = sentence[:]
```

snippet and phrases are parameters whose values will be replaced by list, i.e., snippet and phrase both will be lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Okay, turns out you're asking about something entirely different.

The code you have will not combine `snippet` and `phrase`. On the first iteration of the loop, a copy of `snippet` will be assigned to `result`. On the second iteration, a copy of `phrase` will be assigned to `result`, replacing the old value. If you want to create a list with the elements of both `snippet` and `phrase`, you can just use

```
result = snippet + phrase
```

or if you really want to use a loop,

```
result = []
for sentence in snippet, phrase:
    result += sentence
```

---

`x, y` is a tuple. In other words, it's parsed like this:

```
for i in (x, y):
    do_something(i)
```

That means `do_something` will be called once on `x`, and once on `y`.

If you want to iterate over pairs of corresponding elements from `x` and `y`, use `zip`:

```
for i in zip(x, y):
# or
# for x_element, y_element in zip(x, y):
    do_something(i):
```

If you want to iterate over the elements of `x`, then the elements of `y`, you can use

```
import itertools
for i in itertools.chain(x, y):
    do_something(i)
```

or if `x` and `y` are both lists or both tuples,

```
for i in x + y:
    do_something(i)
```

Comment: @kartikey_kant: See expanded answer.